# Doees the 'this' pointer participate in a virtual function's polymorphic behavior

Tags: c++, this, virtual

I'm implementing the Visitor pattern, and I have an `accept()` function that is only defined in the base `visitable` class. This system works just fine, but Alexandresku states in his book that the `this` pointer has static typing.

Is this code flawed and/or has a bug, but my output is not catching it?

I have tried to change references to pointers, but the output does not change.

.h file

```
class WidgetVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(ConcreteWidget1& w1);
    virtual void visit(ConcreteWidget2& w2);
    virtual void visit(Widget& w);
    virtual ~WidgetVisitor() { }
};


class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(const std::string& text);
    virtual std::string text() const;
    virtual void accept(WidgetVisitor* v);
protected:
    std::string text_;
};


class ConcreteWidget1: public Widget
{
public:
    ConcreteWidget1(const std::string& text);
    virtual std::string text() const override;

};

class ConcreteWidget2: public Widget
{
public:
    ConcreteWidget2(const std::string& text);
    virtual std::string text() const override;
};
```

.cpp file

```
void WidgetVisitor::visit(ConcreteWidget1& w1) {
    cout << w1.text() << '\n';
}

void WidgetVisitor::visit(ConcreteWidget2& w2) {
    cout << w2.text() << '\n';
}

void WidgetVisitor::visit(Widget& w) {
    cout << w.text() << '\n';
}


Widget::Widget(const std::string& text): text_(text) { }

string Widget::text() const {
    return "Widget" + text_;
}

void Widget::accept(WidgetVisitor* v) {
    v->visit(*this);
    cout << "in the class " << text_ << '\n';
}

ConcreteWidget1::ConcreteWidget1(const string& text): Widget(text) { }

string ConcreteWidget1::text() const {
    return "ConcreteWidget1" + text_;
}

ConcreteWidget2::ConcreteWidget2(const string& text): Widget(text) { }

string ConcreteWidget2::text() const {
    return "ConcreteWidget2" + text_;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {

    WidgetVisitor* visitor = new WidgetVisitor();
    std::vector<Widget*> v;
    v.push_back(new Widget(" 1"));
    v.push_back(new ConcreteWidget1(" 2"));
    v.push_back(new ConcreteWidget2(" 3"));
    v.push_back(new ConcreteWidget1(" 4"));

    for (auto & w: v)
        w->accept(visitor);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Widget 1
in the class  1
ConcreteWidget1 2
in the class  2
ConcreteWidget2 3
in the class  3
ConcreteWidget1 4
in the class  4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't actually working like you think it's working.  The only visitor being called is `void WidgetVisitor::visit(Widget& w)` but since the `Widget::text()` method is virtual, all of the visitor methods effectively have the same behavior.

Change the implementations to output the name of the reference argument's type and you'll see:

```
void WidgetVisitor::visit(ConcreteWidget1& w1) {
    cout << "[cw1] " << w1.text() << '\n';
}

void WidgetVisitor::visit(ConcreteWidget2& w2) {
    cout << "[cw2] " << w2.text() << '\n';
}

void WidgetVisitor::visit(Widget& w) {
    cout << "[w] " << w.text() << '\n';
}
```

You get this output:

```
[w] Widget 1
in the class  1
[w] ConcreteWidget1 2
in the class  2
[w] ConcreteWidget2 3
in the class  3
[w] ConcreteWidget1 4
in the class  4
```

So as you can see, the other two visitor overloads are simply not being used.

`this` is indeed statically typed; if it points to a polymorphic type then virtual methods called on it are still dispatched using dynamic dispatch, but `Widget::accept()` isn't actually invoking anything on `this`, it's just taking a reference to it.  When you pass this reference somewhere else it will still be treated as its static type, meaning that overload resolution is still going to pick the `Widget&` overload here, because `this` is always `Widget*`:

```
v->visit(*this);
```

This can work but you have to override `Widget::accept()` in derived classes.  For example:

```
class ConcreteWidget1: public Widget
{
public:
    ConcreteWidget1(const std::string& text);
    virtual std::string text() const override;
    virtual void accept(WidgetVisitor* v) override;
};

void ConcreteWidget1::accept(WidgetVisitor* v) {
    v->visit(*this);
    cout << "in the class " << text_ << '\n';
}
```

Do the same for `ConcreteWidget2` and now you'll notice that the right visitor overload is called:

```
[w] Widget 1
in the class  1
[cw1] ConcreteWidget1 2
in the class  2
[cw2] ConcreteWidget2 3
in the class  3
[cw1] ConcreteWidget1 4
in the class  4
```

Now you'd be able to make `Widget::text()` non-virtual and see exactly the same output.